Check if git maintenance is active?
How can I know whether I have already ran git maintenance start (doc) on a git repository?
The Windows tasks scheduler shows me 3 tasks (hourly, daily, weekly), but no information about which repos are involved.

Check the maintenance.repo config variable at ~/.gitconfig (either by opening the file directly, or with config related comands, i.e. git config --global --get-all maintenance.repo) (Thank you Guildenstern for the useful tip about --get-all, since --get only returns the last value indeed)
It lists all repositories registered for maintenance.
Reference: (doc)

register
Initialize Git config values so any scheduled maintenance will start running on this repository. This adds the repository to the maintenance.repo config variable in the current user’s global config, or the config specified by --config-file option, and enables some recommended configuration values for maintenance..schedule. The tasks that are enabled are safe for running in the background without disrupting foreground processes.


Should have a list subcommand I guess.

Agreed. I guess we can expect more features around git maintenance in the coming versions, this is still fairly new.

I just noticed something. I wanted to test how git wrote multiple repositories in the config variable, so I did git maintenance start on a new empty repo and.... it replaced maintenance.repo altogether with the new repo path, soooo the other repo I had put in maintenance is now... not any more? Annoyingly unexpected.

You need --get-all instead of --get; --get will return the last value for multi-valued config.

@Guildenstern Wonderful, I never stumbled upon this one :-) Editing my answer.
